# Changing what is section is visible on a page

Tags: interface, click, dynamic-ui

I have an event with two sections, where after the first part, people will split to one section of the event or the other. I'm trying to put together a details page for each part of the event, and the idea was to only show one side or the other, since users will only be at one or the other.

Here's the basic design:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9ldQI.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

How can I make it more obvious to users that in order to see Section 2, they will have to click on it?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the mock up you have attached is the actual interface design, then you should style the section buttons to look more like a tab. I have attached a typical tab interface design for your reference.

Consistency is key if you want to reduce the cognitive load on the user to navigate your contents. Use the same link color and tab design through out your app so that its easy for the user to figure out which element is clickable (which is not) and what action it will perform.

**Proposed Mockup**

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSfMSz.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

A good tab design should always group or enclose its content. Hope this gives you a good idea on how to solve your problem.